# Getting Error on shutdown and need to press ok to shutdown

Tags: windows, shutdown, event-viewer

**I get an error box on shutdown.**

[image]

PS! I reinstalled Windows 2 days ago, it doesn't affect.

My list of programs, striped out, what are most likely not the cause:

[image]

[image]

Also, in event log I found the most reasonable one, what goes with it. *My goal is just to hide it/get rid of it, else my pc will not shut down, just by pressing the shutdown button...*

General Tab:

[image]

Details Tab:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows explorer crashes randomly](https://superuser.com/questions/1190973/windows-explorer-crashes-randomly)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev It's not, I was able to confirm it is due to google drive being left in a no support hole.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the faulty module using the info in the corresponding Event Log entry:

[image: event log]
[image: app crash event]

Since the error happens at shutdown, you should search events with timestamps shortly before that of the last system shutdown event which is in System log and looks like this:

[image: system shutdown event]

After having identified the faulty module, either fix it (update the application it's a part of or identify and eliminate the cause), or uninstall or [disable](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) the corresponding shell extension.

Comment: sorry, where do you find it, what tab?

Comment: @KristoferVesi go to Event Viewer and find an event like the above ("Application Error") in the Application log that corresponds to your Explorer crash.

Comment: really dumb, from windwos logs, application, errors of that and even from information can't find anything of explorer... Screenshot?

Comment: @KristoferVesi Added a screenshot.

Comment: About the 2nd i googled, it gave a windows help page, what wanted to download a tool what basically resetted the store and opened it... Don't know if it helped... Ignore the bonjour, it is not the problem, it was not on pc before reinstall and so on, it is meaningless, because synergy... so the 1 http://prntscr.com/ffub49 and the 2nd http://prntscr.com/ffubul

Comment: update: didn't get to fix it, but i think google drive is the possible cause

Comment: confirmed https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/o3MbDsbNHUM/HC-WPEB0XKgJ

Comment: That is not Explorer ("faulting application name: SoftwareUpdate.exe"). There should be something with the timestamp around the shutdown time, i.e. shortly before the shutdown event from `eventlog` in the System log. If there isn't, you have no choice but to write down all the modules in the Explorer (from the lower pane of Process Explorer) and determine which the address in the error message at the shutdown _after that_ is from.

Comment: Didn't read [your last comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1214738/getting-error-on-shutdown-and-need-to-press-ok-to-shutdown/1214781?noredirect=1#comment1776272_1214781) b4 posting that. It still stands if you'd like to make sure.

Comment: Thx for trying to help anyways, they confirmed it is, no solve from them, but news say that they are releasing new sync client with loads of more features, i think they just ditched the old one at some point. Had some problems from google in past, what are really big, google answering nothing.